# How to add and remove text to a string using jQuery

Tags: jquery, string

I have a web form with a hidden input field as follows:

```
<input id="requiredFields" name="requiredFields" type="hidden" value="firstname,lastname,email,phone">
```

I want to add and remove "`,location`" based on a certain condition using jQuery as follows:

```
$('input[name="locationstatus"]:radio').on("change", function() {
    if ($('input[name="locationstatus"]:radio:checked').val() == 'Yes') {
        /* need syntax to append text ',location' to #requiredFields string */
    }
    else {
        /* need syntax to remove text ',location' from #requiredFields string */
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery's `.val()` to update the value of `requiredFields`

```
$('input[name="locationstatus"]:radio').on("change", function() {
    if ($('input[name="locationstatus"]:radio:checked').val() == 'Yes') {
        $('#requiredFields').val($('#requiredFields').val() + ',location');
    }
    else {
        $('#requiredFields').val($('#requiredFields').val().replace(',location',''));
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks streamlined @Sharlike. I am going to test it now and post back.

Comment: Perfect @Sharlike -- exactly what I needed. As soon as SO allows me to accept this as the answer I will do so

Comment: @H.Ferrence Glad it was what you needed

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to append/remove the one part of the string, it would probably be easier and faster to just replace the entire string, assuming that there are no other strings, in which case I can offer a more robust solution.

```
$('input[name="locationstatus"]:radio').on("change", function() {
    if ($('input[name="locationstatus"]:radio:checked').val() == 'Yes') {
        /* need syntax to append ',location' to #requiredFields */
        $('#requiredFields').val('firstname,lastname,email,phone,location');
    }
    else {
        /* need syntax to remove ',location' from #requiredFields */
        $('#requiredFields').val('firstname,lastname,email,phone');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append the location to the end you can use the `.val()` method. It is also capable of setting the value of an element.

```
 $('input[name="locationstatus"]:radio').on("change", function() {
   if ($('input[name="locationstatus"]:radio:checked').val() == 'Yes') {
      var prev = $("#requiredFields").val();
      $("#requiredFields").val(prev + ',location');
   }
   else {
    var newText = $("#requiredFields").val().replace(',location', '');
    $("#requiredFields").val(newText);
   }
 });
```